# Use HBaseStorage to load from Bigtable via Pig on Dataproc

Tags: apache-pig, bigtable, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable, hbasestorage

Does anybody have experience or succeeded on loading data from Bigtable via Pig on Dataproc using HBaseStorage?

Here's a very simple Pig script I'm trying to run. It fails with an error indicating it can't find the BigtableConnection class and I'm wondering what setup I may be missing to successfully load data from Bigtable.

```
raw = LOAD 'hbase://my_hbase_table'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
       'cf:*', '-minTimestamp 1490104800000 -maxTimestamp 1490105100000 -loadKey true -limit 5')
       AS (key:chararray, data);

DUMP raw;
```

Steps I followed to setup my cluster:

1. Launched Bigtable cluster (my_bt); created and populated my_hbase_table
2. Launched Dataproc cluster (my_dp) via cloud.google.com Cloud Dataproc Console
3. Installed HBase shell on Dataproc master (/opt/hbase-1.2.1) following instructions on https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell
4. Added properties to `hbase-site.xml` for my_bt and BigtableConnection class
5. Created file `t.pig` with contents listed above
6. Invoked Pig via command: `gcloud beta dataproc jobs submit pig --cluster my_dp --file t.pig --jars /opt/hbase-1.2.1/lib/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-1.2-0.9.5.1.jar`
7. Got the following error indicating BigtableConnection class not found:

2017-03-21 15:30:48,029 [JobControl] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat - java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection

Comment: I would suggest using the shaded bigtable mapreduce jar, which has all of the dependencies you'll need.  Go to http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cbigtable%20mapreduce,and download "shaded.jar" .

Comment: Looks like `,and` was auto-appended to @SolomonDuskis' URL due to lack of space to separate them; you want to visit http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cbigtable%20mapreduce to download the artifact.

Comment: I downloaded the shaded.jar and get the same error when submitting the pig job. I can upload the output I get when running the test if that helps.

Comment: Can you try to add netty-tcnative-boringssl-static?  See ttp://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.netty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22netty-tcnative-boringssl-static%22%20AND%20v%3A%221.1.33.Fork26%22 and download "jar"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is getting all dependencies on pig's classpath. Using the jars pointed to by Solomon, I've created the following [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/init-actions) that downloads two jars, the bigtable mapreduce jar and netty-tcnative-boringssl, and sets up the pig classpath.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initialization action to set up pig for use with cloud bigtable
mkdir -p /opt/pig/lib/

curl http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/1.1.33.Fork19/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-1.1.33.Fork19.jar \
    -f -o /opt/pig/lib/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-1.1.33.Fork19.jar

curl http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-mapreduce/0.9.5.1/bigtable-hbase-mapreduce-0.9.5.1-shaded.jar \
    -f -o /opt/pig/lib/bigtable-hbase-mapreduce-0.9.5.1-shaded.jar

cat >>/etc/pig/conf/pig-env.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash

for f in /opt/pig/lib/*.jar; do
  if [ -z "\${PIG_CLASSPATH}" ]; then
    export PIG_CLASSPATH="\${f}"
  else
    export PIG_CLASSPATH="\${PIG_CLASSPATH}:\${f}"
  fi  
done
EOF
```

You can then pass in bigtable configuration in the usual ways:

- Via hbase-site.xml
- Specifying properties when submitting a job:

  ```
  PROPERTIES='hbase.client.connection.impl='
  PROPERTIES+='com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection'
  PROPERTIES+=',google.bigtable.instance.id=MY_INSTANCE'
  PROPERTIES+=',google.bigtable.project.id=MY_PROJECT'

  gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig --cluster MY_DATAPROC_CLUSTER \
      --properties="${PROPERTIES}"  \
      -e "f =  LOAD 'hbase://MY_TABLE' 
           USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf:*','-loadKey true') 
           AS (key:chararray, data); 
      DUMP f;"
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: The addition of pig-env.sh did the trick.

But HBaseStorage, has options not supported by the BigTable client API.

I got no results with the min/max timestamp options, but got results with -gte. It seams -lt is not supported.

HBaseStorage uses RowFilter to implement -gte and -lt, but BigTable's implementation of RowFilter does not support that.

What we actually use in our Pig jobs is a custom loader that creates Scan objects and do setStartRow() and setStopRow(). I don't know if those are supported by BigTable. I'll have to experiment.

Thank you for your help.
Eduardo.

Comment: setStartRow() and setStopRow() are indeed supported.  Feel free to raise a github issue in the Cloud Bigtable client library about the RowFilter issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client